# Make Docker build stop after if RUN fails in multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which has multiple stages. An intermediate stage runs tests. If the test fails, I would like the build to stop but it continues given below. You can see output where it continues beyond failed RUN command.

```
# Base image
FROM python:3.5 as base


# For running tests
FROM base
WORKDIR /root

RUN mkdir /root/src
ADD src/requirements.txt /root/src
RUN pip install -r /root/src/requirements.txt

ADD . /root
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd test; ./run-tests.sh"]


# For publishing src files

FROM base
ADD src /root/src
ADD .pypirc /root/.pypirc


WORKDIR /root/src

CMD python setup.py sdist upload -r local
```

Output:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN pip install -r /root/src/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 56fa7fc2f2e8
Step 7/13 : ADD . /root
 ---> 74c52977edcf
Step 8/13 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd test; ./run-tests.sh"]
 ---> Running in 68a184ab54af
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 10.122s

FAILED (failures=1)
The command '/bin/bash -c cd test; ./run-tests.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
running sdist
running egg_info
...
running upload
Submitting dist/<artifact-name>-2.6.1.2.tar.gz to https://<subdomain>.jfrog.io/<context>/api/pypi/python-local
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your command, `run-tests.sh`, needs to exit with a non-zero exit code and docker will stop building. In this case, that has happened:

```
The command '/bin/bash -c cd test; ./run-tests.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Whatever you run to call `docker build` needs to handle that exit code and stop running at that point. Docker's behavior is to give you an exit code to indicate the failure:

```
$ cat df.fail
FROM busybox
RUN exit 1
RUN echo still running

$ docker build -f df.fail .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.04kB
Step 1/3 : FROM busybox
 ---> 59788edf1f3e
Step 2/3 : RUN exit 1
 ---> Running in 70d90fb88d6e
The command '/bin/sh -c exit 1' returned a non-zero code: 1

$ echo $?
1
```

From the above example, you can see that docker does stop as soon as the command returns a non-zero exit code, it does not run the `echo still running` line, and there's a non-zero return code from `docker build` itself that you can handle with whatever you use to run the build.

Comment: as in the output the RUN command failed with exit code `1`. `The command '/bin/bash -c cd test; ./run-tests.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: @Rag I glanced right over that. It looks like the docker build did fail. It's the script that kicked off the docker build that needs the error handling.

Comment: the problem here seems to be it runs the next stage inspite of the failure in the previous stage.

Comment: @Rag If by next stage you're referring to running `python setup.py sdist upload -r local`, you should note that that never runs during the build, even when successful. That runs after the `docker build` command exits. Please update your question with the full output of the `docker build` command, including the command itself, and when you see the prompt appear after the build finishes, if this isn't the case.

Comment: good point. the problem was i had a bash script that built the Docker image and ran the image after. It was not looking at previous command's (Docker build) exit code. I have now `set -e` in place.